# Early 2011 MacBook Pro SMC firmware update question

Tags: power-management

OS has been upgraded to Mavericks. Can I still run the SMC firmware update 1.7 said to be for OS 10.75 and 10.82? Would it hurt anything to try this firmware update with the later OS?

Comment: SMC needs to work with the OS X , so it might not do well.

Answer (score 1):

If software update doesn't prompt you to update, then either it has been circumvented by other updates or it has already been applied.